# Problem with symbol in section

Tags: symbols, sections-paragraphs, mathematics

How to avoid the errors when we put a symbol mathematics in a section?

```
 \section {Répartition des carrés dans $\mathbb{F}_{p}$}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem. I can't reproduce any errors with a very simple article document with the `amssymb` package loaded, for example.

Comment: Are you using [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref)?

Comment: try adding `\protect` before `\mathbb`.  then delete all `.aux` files before recompiling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unable to reproduce your problem and therefore think you might be mistaking your "errors" for *warnings* when you include non-standard math in sectional titles while including [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) or [`bookmarks`](http://ctan.org/pkg/bookmarks).

To avoid such *warnings*, use `\texorpdfstring{<TeX>}{<PDF>}` and provide a suitable `<PDF>` version for you math-rich `<TeX>` content:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts,hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Répartition des carrés dans \texorpdfstring{$\mathbb{F}_p$}{F(p)}}

\end{document}
```